# CoordinatorLayout: How can I prevent scroll events from reaching RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a layout consisting of a `CoordinatorLayout` parent with a `NestedScrollView` containing a `ViewPager`, which contains a `RecyclerView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.snap.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

            </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/id_viewpager_photosvideos_albums"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1000dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout1">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/id_tab_photosvideos_albums"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to achieve the following:

*I want to intercept(prevent) the scroll events from reaching `RecyclerView` until a certain threshold condition is reached. post which, `RecyclerView` shall start intercepting scroll events normally.*

How can I achieve this?

---

**Note:** I have tried looking into `Behavior.onNestedScroll()` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer -

By consuming them like this(in `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`):

```
@Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, NestedScrollView child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
        return (nestedScrollAxes & ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) != 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedPreScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, NestedScrollView child, View target, int dx, int dy, int[] consumed) {

        int mCurrentScrollOffset = target.getScrollY();

        if(mCurrentScrollOffset <= thresholdScrollDistance){
            consumed[1] = dy;
            child.scrollBy(0, dy);
        }
    }
```

**Why?**

Because, `consumed[i]` is an out variable storing x and y scroll unconsumed values for consumption.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this method to intercept the touch on UI elements.

```
findViewById(R.id.recyclerView).setOnTouchListener(this)
```

and then override the **onTouch** method.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
    {
        initialX = event.getX();
        initialY = event.getY();

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
               //
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
               //do something here 

                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

from **view** parameter, you can check which view is **touched** or scrolled and get relative position of touch of the UI element on the screen and then **return

true** to tell the system that I want to consume this touch event and **return

false** to let others handle the touch event.

Comment: Well, this is general. Is there any solution for filtering Scroll events?

Comment: Alright, I know, its possible through this but I want to save time if there is an in-built/less involving method available and I suspect there might be one with all the popularity with CoordinatorLayout

Comment: I guess I know this method only, can you tell me exact condition or requirement on which you want to intercept touch for recyclerview i will try by my method side by side.

Comment: See the answer I posted. Now, that is the method I was searching for and it is quite an elegant one!